# Sort a GridView without going back to SQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

I have a gridview which I am using to display data from a storedProcedure. I now want to sort the data but alot of places are saying I have to go back to sql to do this. Maby im not understanding the explanations given but I dont think thats right. I have simplified the problem and would like any help on how to sort the boundcolumn. here is my aspx page.

```
    <asp:GridView  ID="BannerGrid" runat="server" AllowSorting="True" onSorting="Sorts" GridLines="None" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCreated="BannerGrid_RowCreated">
        <Columns>
            <asp:Boundfield DataField="BannerID" HeaderText="Banner ID" SortExpression="BannerID"/> </Columns>
```

here is my c# code in the back:

```
            SqlConnection sqlConnection1 = new SqlConnection(conn);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "GetDifferenceInteraction";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ADate", TodayDate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BDate", YesDate);
        SqlDataReader reader;
        cmd.Connection = sqlConnection1;

        sqlConnection1.Open();

        reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        BannerGrid.DataSource = reader;
        BannerGrid.DataBind();
        reader.Close();
        sqlConnection1.Close();
```

Any help on how to sort this in c# itelf. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you seen this: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/663532/How-to-Perform-Sorting-in-Gridview-in-ASP-NET

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can store the data on a ViewState variable, but if you data is really big, it can cause problems.

```
...
reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
//here you should save your data, I stored mine in a DataTable type like this
dtStored.Load(reader);
BannerGrid.DataSource = reader;
BannerGrid.DataBind();
reader.Close();
...
```

I have this fourproperties

```
    private const string ASCENDING = " ASC";
    private const string DESCENDING = " DESC";
    private SortDirection gvSortDirection
    {
        get
        {
            if (ViewState["sortDirection"] == null)
                ViewState["sortDirection"] = SortDirection.Ascending;

            return (SortDirection)ViewState["sortDirection"];
        }
        set { ViewState["sortDirection"] = value; }
    }
    private DataTable dtStored
    {
        get { return (ViewState["dt"] == null) ? null : (DataTable)ViewState["dt"]; }
        set { ViewState["dt"] = value; }
    }
```

in your sorting event you can have this

```
    protected void BannerGrid_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        string sortExpression = e.SortExpression;
        string direction = ASCENDING;

        if (gvSortDirection == SortDirection.Ascending)
        {
            gvSortDirection = SortDirection.Descending;
            direction = DESCENDING;
        }
        else
        {
            gvSortDirection = SortDirection.Ascending;
            direction = ASCENDING;
        }
        try
        {   
            DataTable dt = dtStored;

            DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
            dv.Sort = sortExpression + direction;

            BannerGrid.DataSource = dv;
            BannerGrid.DataBind();     
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //Log error
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

IF I remember correctly, What you can do is load the data to a DataSet with a DataTable in it. Then bind it to your GridView.This provides much
 more functionality that would allow your sort. But it will be better to arrange a  query that produces the resultset in the first place.